# c++ error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘secret’

Tags: c++

I do not understand where this error is located. I've spent a few hours on just trying to figure this out but no luck. Using g++ My compiler highlights class secret.

```
#ifndef ENEMIES_H
#define ENEMIES_H


class secret {
private:
int damage;
int accuracy;
int hlth;
public:
int attack(int x);
int health(int x);
};
#endif
```

Comment: What comes _before_ this?  Have you included some other file and forgotten a semicolon?

Comment: @user699647: It must be your enemies... don't `include` them in the coding process next time...

Comment: I've included the header in another file but there isn't any missing semicolons that me or the compiler can pick up.

Answer (score 7):

You're compiling it with a C compiler, not a C++ compiler.  Example:

```
$ cc -c -o example.o example.c
example.c:5: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’
before ‘secret’
make: *** [example.o] Error 1
$ mv example.c example.cpp
$ cc -c -o example.o example.cpp
$
```

Chances are you've done exactly what the above example shows - named the file with a `.c` extension instead of with a `.cpp` or a `.C` or any of the other extensions that GCC will use to decide that your file is written in C++.  You can use the `-x` flag to workaround this error if you don't want to change your filename:

```
$ cc -x c++ -c -o example.o example.c
$
```

Using clang instead of GCC gives better error messages but the same results:

```
$ clang -c -o example.o example.c
example.c:5:1: error: unknown type name 'class'
class secret {
^
example.c:5:13: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
class secret {
            ^
            ;
2 errors generated.
$ clang -x c++ -c -o example.o example.c
$
```

But even better:

```
$ clang++ -c -o example.o example.c
clang++: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, 
this behavior is deprecated
$
```

Which works - but exactly explains your problem.

Comment: It's a header file for a .cpp file. I believe i'm using g++ when I compile and not gcc i might be mistaken.

Comment: @user699647 - what's the command line you use to compile that file?  As you can see, your error matches *exactly* with what happens when you try to compile your example code with a C compiler.

Comment: I'm using Geany, a simple ide. I find the command line a bit tedious, i like having a button for quick compiling. I used your example code for the command line though, and it erase all my code for some odd reason.

Comment: @user699647, you might try looking into `make` if you want convenience but still be able to learn about how the compiler works at a more direct level.  At any rate, your IDE is running *some* kind of command line operation to do the compilation, and it should expose that command to you somewhere.

Comment: I will diffidently check make out then. I just started c++ a few weeks ago and programming in general a few months ago, and I barely just got into constructors and headers files. Ok so it's the compilers fault or i got my extensions mixed up or should i look at other files that included the header?

Answer (score 1):

I think this proplem is that your class file suffix is *.c, not *.cpp, you change suffix to *.cpp. good luck~

Comment: This should be comment not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The bug can be happened even with `.cpp` file extension, when have the right `.h` entry in the HEADERS `.pro` section but the `.cpp` is skipped in the SOURCES.

Usually when `file.h` is copy and pasted to the SOURCES without the extension changing, in that case, the 'make' command also creates the (CC) entry in the makefile instead of (CXX) to process the header only.